# Combine Specific Columns from Multiple CSVs into a Single CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have 67 csv files with over 1gb of data combined. Each CSV contains 20 columns, but I need only 3 of those columns per csv file. I can successfully combine all of them into a single csv file, but this creates a mammoth file that I don't need. Instead, I want only 3 of those columns from all 67 files combined into a single file (of course, with only three columns).

[screen capture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC3Bh.png)

My current error message is the index out of range error, but I don't know how to fix that within this code.
Here is the code that I am using:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = "C:/Correct/Path"

file_list = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

csv_list = []

for file in file_list:
    csv_list.append(pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=1, usecols=[9], engine='python'))

csv_merged = pd.DataFrame()

for csv_file in csv_list:
    
    csv_merged = csv_merged.append(
    csv_file, ignore_index=True)

csv_merged.to_csv('all_counties.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily write a little script with standard the library modules [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.htm) and [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('C:/Correct/Path') 

file_list = p.glob("*.csv")

desired_columns = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
desired_rows = []

for csv_file in file_list:
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            desired_rows.append({c: row[c] for c in desired_columns})

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=desired_columns)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(desired_rows)
```

input of two different csvs:

```
foo,bar,baz,spam,eggs
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5

foo,baz,bar,spam,eggs,unused
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

output:

```
foo,bar,baz
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,3,2
```

From there you've got your cleaned data and are free to use pandas as you see fit.

E:
To remove duplicate dicts from `desired_rows` you have a few options, depending on the dicts themselves. The general gist of it would be

```
new_list = []
for d in desired_rows:
    if d not in new_list: 
        new_list.append(d)
```

Comment: I'm too new to actually upvote this (need rep of 15), but this DOES WORK. Thank you!
I do have a follow up question, if you're game!

Comment: The follow up involves compressing the data even more. There are many lines that repeat, e.g., ZIP: 32609, COUNTY: ALACHUA, COUNTYID: 1 appears 11 times in the merged data set.

Is there a way to add code which compresses all duplicates into a single line? (I'm aiming for this to be done along with the file merging, i.e., code that is within what you have already given me.

Comment: @PhDStudentFSU I've edited the answer with a few tips on some ways you could do that